# STM32CubeMX crushing for jdk file

Tags: java, java-8, stm32, hardware, stm32cubemx

I am having a problem running STM32cubeMX 5.3.0 on my Windows 11. My jdk version is 20 and the jri version is 1.8.0_361(recommended to run STM32CubeMX). So, when I have jdk in my system My STM32CubeMX crush, it dont want to start. In my cmd when my java version is 1.8.0_361 and javac is 20.

But when I uninstall jdk from my computer it works just fine.

I want to run my STM32CubeMX when my Jdk is installed. I want to know how  can I do that ?

Comment: When I couldn't start Cube it was because updated version of Cube needed 64bit version of jre. So I'd check if you don't have 64b jre and 32b jdk